# How to Deploy rails application using apache2 and apache tomcat server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, tomcat, jruby

Hi I am new to ruby on rails and I want to deploy my rails app using web server apache2 and application server tomcat and jruby.I have installed tomcat 8.0.36 and apache2.My application runs on tomcat server IP_ADDRESS:8080.

apache2 folders:

apache2.conf    conf-enabled  magic  mods-enabled  sites-available
conf-available  envvars  mods-available  ports.conf    sites-enabled

Please suggest me how to connect both these server and deploy.If my idea is wrong then suggest me what are the best way to deploy rails app.

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy using this link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks,It can be useful for jruby application also.

Comment: mostly for jruby, you should follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jruby-to-run-a-rails-application-on-apache-tomcat-7-and-ubuntu-14-04